# Add informations for geometry column

Tags: postgis, sql, geometry

I create a table with a geometry column (geom2)

```
 CREATE TABLE reu_oin_oi2 AS
 (SELECT eingangsdaten.*,
 ST_Intersection (test.geom, eingangsdaten.geom) as geom2
 FROM test, eingangsdaten
 JOIN test b
 ON ST_Intersects (eingangsdaten.geom, b.geom)
 WHERE test.id = 2);
```

Now some informations for the geometry column are missing (type of polygon ('Polygon') and SRID)
How can I add these inside the ST_Intersection command?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Populate_Geometry_Columns()` after your query.

In your case:

```
SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('reu_oin_oi2'::regclass::oid);
```

However, this will only work for those columns that have the same geometry type for each row. The result of ST_Intersection is often very diverse (e.g. a mix of `ST_MultiPolygon`, `ST_Polygon` and `ST_GeometryCollection`). You may want to use `ST_Dump()`:

```
CREATE TABLE reu_oin_oi2 AS (
    SELECT 
        eingangsdaten.*,
        (ST_Dump(ST_Intersection (test.geom, eingangsdaten.geom) AS geom2
    FROM 
        test, 
        eingangsdaten
    JOIN 
        test b
    ON 
        ST_Intersects (eingangsdaten.geom, b.geom)
    WHERE 
        test.id = 2
);

SELECT Populate_Geometry_Columns('reu_oin_oi2'::regclass::oid);
```

However, be aware that in this way, any intersection between a geom from the eingangsdaten table and a geom from the test table that consists of more than one piece, will result in one than one row in your reu_oin_oi2 table.

Comment: the result is null.  I can add further informations for a geometry column with `ALTER TABLE reu_oin_oi2
   ALTER COLUMN geom2 TYPE geometry(MultiPolygonZ,4326) USING ST_Multi(geom);` but then my polygon seems to be not correct anymore...

Comment: @Moehre, what you have said here in your comment is what I would have suggested trying... you should add this to your question. How is the polygon not correct after this?

Comment: inside the result table of the ST_Intersection(schablone.geom, eingangsdaten.geom) are different geometries (like MultiPolygon, GeometryCollection). I have to use a tool which is importing the table in QGIS but therefore I need to add Informations for the geometry column (SRID, typ of geometry). Is it possible to convert the different types of geometries in one typ? hope you get it...